# Firefox isn't redirecting after window.print();

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect, printing, window.location

I've got a web page with a button that I want to print the page and then redirect to another page. However, using Firefox 66, if I go through with the print, it doesn't redirect. If I cancel the print, it redirects just fine.

Here's the code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function myprint() {
    window.print();
    window.location='mypage.php';
  }
</script>

<a><button onClick="myprint(); return false;">Print ticket</button></a>
```

If I remove the `window.print();` line, it works fine, but when actually printing, it does not. Also works on Chrome, Edge, and even IE11, but not Firefox.

Am I missing something?

Update: It's not just my computer. Other peoples' computers do the same on Firefox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code should work, but a (way) better version is:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function myprint() {
    window.onafterprint = function(event) {
        window.location.href = 'index.php'
    };

    window.print();
  }
</script>

<a><button onClick="myprint(); return false;">Print ticket</button></a>
```

Where you create a function wich should trigger *after* the print is done.
This event (window.onafterprint) is supported by every browser except safari (EDIT: yep, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint#Browser_compatibility))

Now, for some reason, this code don't work with Firefox 66.0.3 64bit (in my case), but work flawlessly with IE11 and Chrome 73.

Well, actually it **work** if you cancel the print when asked, but not if you actually print.

A work around is to use the other event, `onbeforeprint`, which change the page before printing (the idea is to remove things like ads before printing and then use onafterprint to restore the page).
When i tryed, it seems to print the first page and not the second, so this event is broken too.

This way seems to work.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function myprint() {
    window.onbeforeprint = function(event) {
        window.location.href = 'index.php'
    };

    window.print();
  }
</script>

<a><button onClick="myprint(); return false;">Print ticket</button></a>
```

Comment: **Firefox 65** (on a ubuntu 18.04 machine) show the same behavior: `onBeforePrint` seems really the only way.

Comment: It is insane that that actually works...unless i am misunderstanding how onbeforeprint is supposed to work. i actually tried onafterprint beforehand, with no good results. thought i was going crazy. thank you.

Comment: so, what is the purpose of onafterprint in Firefox? because onafterprint worked just fine in all the other browsers.

Comment: I did a rapid search on google, and i'm pretty sure it's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214805). A really old bug, seems to be.

As for the behavior of the two events, this what you can read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint): `The beforeprint and afterprint events allow pages to change their content before printing starts (perhaps to remove a banner, for example) and then revert those changes after printing has completed.`

Comment: **Firefox 109.0.1** and this is still an issue. So frustrating.